# Sharepoint online - how to request file with special character in name through rest api

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

Sharepoint online now allows # and % characters in filenames:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Blog/New-support-for-and-in-SharePoint-Online-and-OneDrive-for/ba-p/60357

Is it possible to retrieve a file like that using the sharepoint api?

Let's assume i have a file called test%file.pdf.

When making a request such as:

```
Request ->
https://mytestbed-my.sharepoint.com/personal/SOMEFAKEVALUE/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl
(@v)/$value?@v='/personal/SOMEFAKEVALUE/Documents/test%file.pdf'
```

I receive a response:

```
Response ->
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "The query string \"serverRelativeUrl\" is missing or invalid."
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a specific way to escape this or is this not supported in the sharepoint api?   If I encode a '%' it results in a '%25' which causes the same issue.

Thanks!
Ruel Loehr